# tvOS Invalid Toolchain when Submitting tvOS 9.1 app

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, tvos

I'm trying to submit a tvOS app through iTunes Connect, and every time I try I get the following message:

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and tvOS 8 SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software.

I have made sure to update Xcode to it's newest App Store version, and I'm not using any beta software.

Comment: Have you found a workaround @farski ?

Comment: Nope. Not in any rush, so I'm just going to give it a few days and try again.

Comment: Oh, I've been trying for over a month. I found a workaround, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I never ended up resolving this issue completely, I did find a workaround.

When submitting an app, iTunes Connect checks the compiled app's compatibility to the latest operating system (in this case, for tvOS 9.1 `build 13U85`). While compatibility is completely fine between the two, Xcode has a bug. During the archiving process, Xcode specified my archive as `Build 13U78` which is inaccurate and not correct.

A workaround I found, which is quite simple, changes the archive's build from (in my case) `build 13U78` to `build 13U85`.

First, we'll create an archive which is self explanatory.
Second (and this is essential) we need to do the following:

Open 'Show in Finder'

[image: Open 'Show in Finder']

Next, you need to right-click your archive and choose 'Show Package Content'

[image: Next, you need to right-click your archive and choose 'Show Package Content']

Then go to Products, then Applications, then repeat the second step (right click the .app file, then choose 'Show Package Content').

Once you're there, open the Info.plist file.
You'll see some version information in it, but what we want are:

`DTSDKBuild`
...
`DTPlatformBuild`

These two options should be something like:

`DTPlatformBuild 13U78`
...
`DTSDKBuild 13U78`

Modify `13U78` to be the most recent build of tvOS, or in my case:

`DTPlatformBuild 13U85`
...
`DTSDKBuild 13U85`

You're almost done! Just save the modified Info.plist file and close it out. Then Submit to App Store- you're done!

**Make absolutely sure you're using the most recent build of tvOS.**